# I'm trying to create a Python script that requests information from a website and I need this information to be sent to gsheets

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, package.json

I'm new to Python and I was hoping you guys could help me ... I'm using BeautifulSoup to get information from the website, this works the way I need it, I also need to send this information to a Google sheet, i already enabled the API and made it work via cloud console, I tested it and I was able to send some information to it, but when I try to send this dataframe as .json file I get this error code :

> ```
> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
> ```
>
> https: ... valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json returned "Invalid
> value at 'data.values[0]'

What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

    url0 = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2023_skaters.html"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url0).content,"html.parser")

    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'stats_table'})

    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
    df = df[df["Player"] !="Player"]
    df = df [["Player","Pos","GP","G","A","+/-","S%","PS","FO%"]]
    df.fillna(0,inplace=True)

    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

    creds = None
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    gsheet = '******'
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    var2 = [df.to_json()]
    request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=gsheet, range="MasterTest!A1",valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",body={"values":var2}).execute()
```

Thanks

BeautifulSoup is fine, the API has been enabled and it is able to get and update info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is showing because the API is waiting for a 2D array, `var2` needs to look similar to:

```
[['2023-01-18', '1234', 'ABC', 1234], 
['2023-01-17', '5678', 'DEF', 5678], 
['2023-01-16', '9012', 'ABC', 9012]]
```

Sheets will then add each inner Array on its own row. I made the following function to transform your data from a dictionary to a 2D array that the API can use:

```
def transformData(dict):
    firstkey = list(dict)[0]
    lastInnerKey = list(dict[firstkey])[-1]
    main_db = []
    row = []

    for i in range(0, lastInnerKey + 2):
        if i == 0:
            for x in dict:
                row.append("'" + x) # Appending ' to the start of a 
                # value tells Google Sheets that this is text and not a formula.
        else:
            for x in dict:
                if (i - 1) in dict[x]:
                    row.append(dict[x][i - 1])
        if len(row) > 0:
            main_db.append(row)
        row = []

    return main_db
```

Then you just need to update the declaration of var2:

```
var2 = transformData(df.to_dict())
```

---

#### Reference

- Using [ListValue format](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#resource:-valuerange) for the `body`

Comment: Thank you, Mr M ! Your function just needs a little adjustment as I lose the first row and I get an error in column F (Formula parse error), I guess both have to do with the headers in some way ... How can this be fixed ? I tried playing around with your code with no success.

Comment: I removed the first "if" on your code and send the info to A2 instead of A1. This is working fine for me now ... thanks again !

Comment: I updated the code to prevent first and last row loss. The ```Formula parse error``` was showing because Google Sheets takes the ```+``` as the beginning of a formula.